# How to get last page visited in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, referer

is there a way to get or store the last page visited?  Example if I'm on a List Page with a New link that loads a page with form.  If the user cancels, you go back to the previous page (List Page).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in web forms, you would use: Request.UrlReferrer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

So I assume you can also use that in MVC, accessible through the HttpContext property of the RequestContext acessible by teh controller.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, found the same idea here: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t102171-go-back-to-previous-page-when-cancel-button-hit.html